# Is this kind of card navigation possible w React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, card

Alright, new to React Native and trying to nail this kind of Card navigation system. Like this, but you can just tap the left or right to navigate instead of scroll: https://dribbble.com/shots/8257559-Movie-2-0

Another example (the beginning): https://dribbble.com/shots/4466216-Yellow-shadow

My UI looks like this essentially:

[image]

Where (ideally), when cards move out of the screen, opacity lowers, and the scaling animation is incorporated from the above example. Would like to swipe up to fill screen with the card.

Ive looked at https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/before-you-start/ and basic navigation tutorials but wanted to see whether theres a relevant plugin on github or a clear place to dive in.
How can I accomplish this card style navigation?

Answer (score 0):

This, although complex, is definitely doable regardless of which navigation library you pick. I would implement this using `react-navigation` like so:

- Create a screen that contains a horizontal list of cards. You can listen to the scroll events and animate the scale and opacity of the content accordingly using the default `Animated` module or `react-native-reanimated`.
- Use [react-native-shared-element](https://github.com/IjzerenHein/react-native-shared-element) to animate images when navigating between screens.

The rest really doesn't have much to do with navigation and is more in the realm of gestures and animation.